# How to include objects from JavaScript files in Jade?

Tags: javascript, pug

A web app I'm working on needs to be translated. I was reading a tutorial on i18n [here](http://rbeere.tumblr.com/post/41212250036/internationalization-with-express-jade-and) but a colleague suggests that I could simply link to a JavaScript script and access the objects within that JavaScript script in my Jade file. I googled and looked through SO for ways to include JavaScript objects in Jade files and tried this, after several other similar things:

```
doctype html
html
head
    title Muh Web App
link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="css/muh-stylesheet")
    script(type="text/javascript", src="js/muh-scripts.js")
    script(type="text/javascript", src="js/en-translation.js")
body 
    block append content
    - var translate = { translation: '' + Lang.login.loginToMuhApp + '' }
    h1 #{translate.translation}
```

The translation script looks like this:

```
Lang = {
   login: 'Login to Muh Web App'
}
```

But this errors. If I create the objects in the Jade file I can insert one in the h1 tag in this way. But doesn't seem to work when I'm trying to link to an object in a JavaScript file elsewhere.

Can I make my Jade files translateable in this way? Or should I further investigate i18n?

Comment: why you don't inject your object from server-side?

Comment: That's what i18n does (I think). Are you suggesting that doing it the way I'm doing it in the above example cannot work? i.e. Linking to a JavaScript file via a script tag, trying to access the object from there